Edit Excel file from MS Access using vba
I have a MS Access database that exports a queries as sheets to an excel file. Then (this is the part where I'm getting stuck) it is supposed to open the newly created excel file, apply conditional formatting, close and save the excel file. And finally, create a folder (using today's date) and moving the excel file to the newly created folder.
Here is the code that I am using. I get a run-time error '75' (path/file access). But sometimes the code gets stuck in the middle of formatting the excel file. Any help will be appreciated. Note: the code for conditional formatting is from 'recording a macro'.
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "query1", _
    "C:\Archive\MyFile " & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yy") & ".xlsx", True, "MySheet1"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "query2", _
    "C:\Archive\MyFile " & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yy") & ".xlsx", True, "MySheet2"
    Call createFolder

    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Object  'Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSh As Object  'Excel.Worksheet
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   'New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\Archive\MyFile " & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yy") & ".xlsx")
    Set xlSh = xlWB.Sheets("MySheet1")
    
    xlApp.Visible = True
        
    Set xlWB = ActiveWorkbook
       'What follows is code from recording a macro to format a date column with red
        Sheets("MySheet1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
     End With
     With Selection.Font
     .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
     .TintAndShade = 0
     End With
     ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-1
     Range("H2").Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
     Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
     "=AND(LEN(H2)>0,TODAY()-H2>=15)"
     Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
     With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
     .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
     .TintAndShade = 0
     End With
     With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
     .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
     .Color = 255
     .TintAndShade = 0
      End With
      Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("A2").Select
    'the close the book
    Close Workbook
     'move today's file to folder with today's date
     Dim sfolder As String
     Dim dfloder As String

     sfolder = "c:\Archive\"
     dfolder = "c:\Archive\" & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yy") & "\"
     Name sfolder & "MyFile " & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yy") & ".xlsx" As dfolder & "prefix " & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yyyy") & ".xlsx"
     End function
     
Public Sub createFolder()

    'Create the subfolders with today's date
    If Len(Dir("c:\\Archive\" & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yy"), vbDirectory)) = o Then
    MkDir "c:\Archive\" & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yy")
    Else
    MsgBox ("folder with today's date already exists. Plesae check.")
 
    End If


End Sub


If Len(Dir("c:\\Archive\" & Format(Date, "mm-DD-yy"), vbDirectory)) = o Then Should be 0 not o   Please try to properly indent code when posting: it makes it much easier to read...   Why not create the folder before exporting the Excel data though?  It's easier than moving the file after the export.

What does  Close Workbook do? did you want to xlWB.Close? Also 'c:\Archive`  is wrong, it could be c:\Archive

You can't use recorded Excel VBA like this outside of Excel. It will work only once per Access session. See here how to rework your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Thanks @TimWilliams ! that was it. I needed to replace 'o' with zero. Also I removed 'close Workbook' and replaced it with xlWB.Close. The double backslashes was a typo. The code now works!
